How to preserve file permissions in a bluetooth transfer
I have had some success transferring files from one Raspberry Pi to another by using obexftp to send a file to an RPI that is running obex-bt. However, on the receiving end the file's permission is changed from -rw-r--r-- to -rw------- . Does anyone know of a way to preserve the permissions or a work around that would allow a non-superuser that is a different user that sender to access it on the receiving end?

I don't use obexftp BUT most FTP clients have options to preserve attributes so check the documentation for your chosen FTP client. If it doesn't have the option choose a better client.

OBject EXchange (aka 'obex') is a "communication protocol that facilitates the exchange of binary objects between devices.". As a "communication protocol" it has no notion of the properties of filesystems (such as ownership, permissions, etc).
So - the permissions aren't actually changed - the permissions are simply irrelevant to 'obex'. When the file transfer is completed - as far as 'obex' is concerned - that is the end of it.
WRT your question, perhaps the easiest way to "preserve permissions" may be to wrap your obex file transfer in a small shell script that sets the permissions after the file is transferred. Another way may be to add some code that reflects the conventions of the respective "to" and "from" filesystems.
